# Copying partitions from larger HDD to smaller SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So I have a laptop with a HDD of 1TB and I'm planning to buy a 500GB SSD, and copy the HDD to the SSD. Many posts already start like this, and I have read many of them, most on this site. Some recommend using `Clonezilla`, some others to use `gparted`. It seems, though, that when going from a larger drive to a smaller one, neither `Clonezilla` or `gparted` will copy the entire drive (please, correct me if I'm wrong); the way to go about this is to copy partition by partition. I'd like to expose what I'm planning to do to dump the HDD into the SSD just to see if the steps are correct. I would like the people in the community to tell me whether or not I'm doing something wrong and/or if I'm missing something.

First off, this is my hard drive. Nothing outside the norm.
[image]

What I'm planning to do is the following:

1. Create two partitions into my SSD of about roughly the same size, say, 250 GB each, one formatted `ntfs` and the other `ext4`. I suppose with the same flags as in the HDD.
2. Using `gparted`, shrink the partitions `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5` in the HDD down to 250 GB each (or even less, just in case).
3. Using `gparted`, copy the partitions `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sda5` from the HDD to the corresponding partition in the SSD (the `ntfs`-formatted partition from the HDD to the `ntfs`-formatted partition in the SSD; do likewise for the other)
4. Repair the `grub` by, for example, following the steps [in this web](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-fix-grub-error-no-such-partition-grub-rescue).

I've got a few doubts about these steps: Are they complete, i.e., is something missing? What about the other partitions `/dev/sda1` (the `/boot/efi`), `/dev/sda2` (Microsoft reserved partition), `/dev/sda4` (I don't know what that is), and `/dev/sda6` (the swap partition for ubuntu): should they be copied too?

I'm not new to Ubuntu, but I'm new to copying and moving partitions, so any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Microsoft requires gpt partitioning for UEFI boot which you have. And it wants these partitions: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations Often easier to just reinstall Ubuntu to avoid issues of duplicate UUIDs.

Comment: I assume you mean install ubuntu in the new SSD, from scratch, and copy the data. What about windows? I can't simply get rid of it (although sometimes I wish...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got my HDD replaced by an SSD. In this answer I would like to describe the setbacks that I run into after the HDD was copied. I also describe the issues during the copy encountered by the IT technician who did the copy.

I must say, though, that the SSD was indeed smaller than the HDD, but rather than being about half the size, the SSD was just 40 GB smaller than the HDD (the size that appears in `gparted` is 894.25 GB). Therefore, the copy was done by hand (or so the IT technician involved told me). However, it was not done so too comfortably.

## Issues during the copy

The partitions were copied one by one in the left-to-right order in which they appear in gparted (see post). After copying `/dev/sda3`, it was shrunk in the SSD (not in the HDD) so that `/dev/sda5` would fit.

## Issues after the copy

**Booting**

Everyone must make sure that the computer boots all OS normally after the copy and always before wiping out the HDD. This goes without saying but a friendly reminder is always welcome: there were some troubles when booting windows. The technician told me he had to run several windows commands. However, I don't remember which, nor how he did it.

**Running the OS**

*Windows*: there were two issues with Windows update. To begin with, a little trifle: Windows Update widget wouldn't load the list of new updates. This was resolved by deleting the contents of the folder containing what I believe is the updates cache. The second issue is that Windows wouldn't install certain updates, crashing with the error `Windows couldn't finish the update`. After hours of trying several possible solutions I gave up since the update that failed was "optional". (*fix explained later*)

*Ubuntu*: you know that after certain updates (through `apt update ; apt upgrade`), `apt` runs commands that reinstall the grub (or reconfigures grub-related files -- I don't know the exact terminology nor the exact procedure). For example, this happens when updating the Linux kernel. The issue with Ubuntu was that after some time using the SSD, Ubuntu installed some updates which made the computer boot directly into Ubuntu, bypassing the grub (thus Windows was no longer accessible).

*Fixing Windows and Ubuntu*: I started by trying to fix the grub by running the `boot repair` tool in Ubuntu. This shed light on the error: the boot repair tool couldn't repair the grub the flags of the partitions weren't copied properly, so it couldn't find the partition were the grub was installed (in my case `/dev/sda1` with flags `boot,esp`). The flags weren't set properly probably due to "miscopying" the partitions: I checked the flags of the partitions in the SSD and, as far as I can remember, the only flag in the partitions was `msftdata`. So, I set the flags to the appropriate values (following the screenshot in the original post) and I was finally able to repair the grub, and log into Windows and install the updates normally.

## Software used

Unfortunately, I don't know what software was used to copy the HDD into the SSD, sorry about that. But I believe that `gparted`, `clonezilla` as it [was pointed out by Thomas Alchinger](https://askubuntu.com/a/1329930/1165858), or `Macrium Reflect Free` [as suggested by PonJas](https://askubuntu.com/a/1330700/1165858) would be good enough choices.

Comment: +1, Thanks for sharing your experience :-) I understand that there was a lot of work, that could have been avoided if the target drive was at least as big as the source drive. The price for a big enough SSD today is much lower than the cost for fixing these problems (in a commercial context; it might be different at home, when we talk about the budget for your hobby).

Comment: Happy to help! The copy was done by the IT technician, but yes, it seems there was a lot of work due to the SSD being smaller than the HDD. I don't know much about prices but the SSD cost around 110€ (VAT included).

Answer (score 2):

I would do that with clonezilla.

https://clonezilla.org/

Comment: `Clonezilla` is a good tool indeed. I tried it some time ago and seems to do the job. But could you fill in with a few more details? For example, what about the linux swap partition? Do I also have to make a new partition in the SSD flagged as a swap partition? Or will `gparted`/`clonezilla` create it? Is `gparted` replaceable by `clonezilla` in the steps I gave?

Comment: Download the clonezilla iso-file and create a bootable medium. Boot that and you get a menu where you can copy sectorwise partitions or hdd's

Comment: Yes... That I knew, thank you. I suppose you don't have much to say about the smaller partitions (linux swap, ....)? If you know something about that, I would really appreciate it if you mentioned it.

Comment: If you are cloning your disk you need to copy all the components. It’s generally better to have swap space but not essential. If you don’t copy swap without turning swap off you can expect some issues. You can change swap partitions to swap files in Ubuntu but that just moves the space requirement to the Linux partition. You absolutely need the EFI partition, your system will not boot without it and normal boot repair approaches will not work.

Comment: I would recommend to always turn off all swap partitions. For me it's better to use a swap file.

Comment: @PonJar Thank you for spelling out that I need to copy all the components. I really wasn't sure; now I am, thank you :) Also, thanks for filling in extra details like "It's generally better ...". If you have something else to say, I'll be happy to read it!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get this done and don’t mind using Windows based tools Macrium Reflect Free will do the whole job in a single process.

https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW7/Cloning+a+disk

Comment: Thanks for the information, I didn't know this software. Unfortunately, I can't help realising that it is non-free software, the cheapest purchase price being 63€. I don't think throwing money into the problem will help much. I'm only concerned about the Linux swap partitions. Could someone say whether or not those smaller partitions need to be copied? I don't mind copying everything, and creating more than 2 partitions (I've done this before, it's just that OSs weren't involved) but I need to know whether it is necessary or not.

Comment: The free version will do what you have asked unless your comment is about open source vs proprietary. You need all the partitions as indicated by several comments

Comment: My comment was not open source vs proprietary. It's just that I didn't want to pay for a software when there are good open source alternatives, and I believe there are (like gparted and clonezilla). However, since you say there is a free version (which I haven't been able to find yet), I'll read more about the software to learn how to do all this with it and consider using it instead of the open source tools.

Comment: https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

Comment: Second useful comment from you, thank you